# MySQL: Selecting all the rows which are related with a particular value from another row

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql table. I have been trying to select all the rows which are related with the row that has `B` as value in the `code` column. The relation is based on the value of the column `trans_id`

```
id   trans_id  code  amount   side
1      1         A    200     left
2      1         B    200     right
3      2         J    100     right
4      2         C    100     right
5      2         B    200     left
6      3         A    630     right
7      3         K    630     left
```

My Expected Result:

```
  id   trans_id  code  amount   side
  1      1         A    200     left
  3      2         J    100     right
  4      2         C    100     right
```

Could you please tell me what should be the mysql query to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: can you provide expected result ? you can use where condition to fetch all rows that code value = 'B'

Select * from yourtable where code='B'

Comment: @Sudhakar I have edited my question. Please check my post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should return the results you want. This uses a select query to return results to the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable 
WHERE trans_id IN (
    SELECT trans_id FROM yourTable WHERE code='B'
) 
AND code!='B'
```

Comment: Great :) Answer submitted by Chris should also give you the same result, now it depends on your table indexes and data which query would perform faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but as far as I understand, you could use a self join like this:

```
select a.id, 
       a.trans_id, 
       a.code, 
       a.amount, 
       a.side 
    from table as a
    inner join table as b on (a.id=b.trans_id and b.code='B');
```

This will return the row with table.id=2:

```
id   trans_id  code  amount   side
2      1         B    200     right
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    t1.* 
from 
    table_name t1 
        inner join table_name t2 on t1.trans_id = t2.trans_id 
where 
    t2.code = 'B' and 
    t2.code <> t1.code
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly then a subquery would get you what you need.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id IN (SELECT trans_id FROM yourTable WHERE code='B')
```